# cubicle cloud computing

Tags: cloud, cluster-computing

I wondering is there anyone use company cubicle desktop or laptop to composite a cluster or cloud computing? For example, I'd like to use the following machines to composite a cluster:

- 20 desktop, each machine has 2~3G RAM, 1Tb Disk, linux machine
- 100M ethernet with internal IP.
- Sun(Oracle) Grid Engine
- no NAS

  How to make sure:
- high available
- high performance

  Is there anyone have similar experience to share?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Sure; in the early days of building clusters, you used to see the term NOW (Network of workstations) fairly commonly to describe this configuration.

There are problems with this configuration, of course.  The slow network and likely long latencies make it unsuitable for some sorts of cluster computing workflows; but for other sorts it works just fine.   Power is another consideration; desktop computers are nowhere near as power-efficient as specialized cluster nodes would be.

But the advantages are obvious -- you already have these machines, and can make further use of them.

The [Condor](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/) project made its name in the NOW days by taking advantage of these sorts of configurations, although it has long since grown other capabilities, as well.   One of its strengths in this type of situation is that it has very flexible rules for deciding when the computer is available for jobs and when it is not (eg, when someone sits down at it).

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I want to construct a cubicle cluster in a small company, so the environment could be not so dynamic: I mean the desktop is relative available, and also I could limit the cluster usage in the R&D's compute. But as you said, the slow network is a problem. Given all of above, are there any good app stack for me?

Comment: What sort of applications will you be running?  The "best" answer depends a lot on what you need from the cluster.   If it's going to be serial jobs, I would seriously consider condor for this sort of application.  But if the images across workstations are all the same, you could probably run OGE just about anything else, too.  You can play with this sort of thing by playing with http://bccd.net/ -- you can set up a prototype cluster without even installing any software on the workstations.

Comment: the applications I run are: compile C++ application; run test cases for the application; some benchmark for the application as well. All of them could be run in batch mode. Because currently I've deployed Sun(Oracle) Grid Engine, maybe add only a few other tools could be better choice? Additional, are there any solution to improve the network performance(hardware, software)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so these are all serial tasks, so the network shouldn't really be an issue.   (And there's nothing you could do about it anyway other than replacing it).   If you've already deployed OGE in the past, then it may be simplest to go with the tool you already know.   Note that since there's no shared file system, you'll need to make sure the relevant tools (compilers, OGE stack, etc) are installed everywhere in consistent locations, and when you do a compile (say) you'll have to bundle up everything you need (source code, scripts, etc) and copy them over (and the results back) with each job.

Comment: Network could be performance bottleneck. NFS is used for share files. But I found the performance(might because of network) is not good. Any solution to improve it?

Comment: There's no software tool to magically improve server speeds or network speeds.   There are always things you could do for tuning (eg, the NFS parameters listed here - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-tuning-nfs-server-client-performance/ ) and get an extra 10-20% out of your system, but you'd probably need to replace hardware to get a big effect.   Best is probably to start with what you have, then find out which things are really bottlenecking you and then make the case to someone with budget authority to do targetted upgrades.